# jQuery strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:dataTable and there i have a rich column with a span.
When the page is loading this span takes some values like: true+false or true+true etc.

Depending on this value, i hide the tr containing this span with jQuery like:

```
<rich:jQuery query="ready(function() {
jQuery('#inbox:_inboxTable_').find('span[title=test]').each(function(i, o){
        if (jQuery(this).text() == 'true+false' ){
            jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
        }
});
})"/>
```

All it's working OK on Internet Explorer and Chrome but on Firefox is something strange:
- when the page is loading normally, the tr are hidden OK but when i do an ajax request (change the page number or size) ALL THE COMPONENTS from the page are faded out...

can u give me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!!!
- closest('tr') has harmfull behaviour in Firefox. So, instead of using:

```
jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
```

the solution is to use parent by parent until you find the 'tr' of the span:

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like as if the webpage layout is table based and the `closest('tr')` somehow returned the body's first table row wherein the entire content is placed.

Besides, it wonders me that you seem to think that the very same `rich:jQuery` query is been executed after every ajax request, because the `ready()` is in fact **only** executed during page load. Don't you have another jQuery/JS pieces somewhere else in your page? Or are your ajax requests maybe not as asynchronous as they ought to be?

The information you provided as far is by the way very brief. Please try to elaborate the problem at code level, not from higher levels. Do not only tell in enduser's perspective what happened, but also tell in developer perspective what happened at code level. What lines get executed and what not. What were the values of the variables which goes around. That kind of things a developer ought to know.

If not done yet, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and use its great Javascript debugger.

Comment: You were right....after the ajax request, the closest('tr') 'becomes' the first row of the main table, which is very strange...because the span is in the same place.. i do not understand why FF founds it ok when the page is loading and after the ajax request it found it's but wrongly returns the closest tr...

Comment: That's exactly why I suggested Firebug.

Comment: i debugged it with firebug and surprise: when doing ajax stuff the jquery function is not touched :-oo (but if i put a restriction, for instance to check the parent id of the tr, to not be the id of the main table, the table is not hidden anymore)..so in firebug not touched but in reality it matters...

Comment: Maybe you didn't use Firebug the right way. Hard to tell from distance. **Some** Javascript must be invoked, there is certainly no means of magic. It's just the code.